# Trying to get property 'username' of non-object after POST to external website and redirect back to my website in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, api, post

Auth::user() has a POST request to an external website with the following:

postfile.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ url('https:www.external.com/api/') }}" method="POST" align="center">
                      @csrf
                      @method('POST')
                    <input type="hidden" name="Data1" value="{{ $Data1}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Data2" value="{{ $Data2}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Data3" value="{{ $Data3}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURLOK" value="{{ url('/success') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURLError" value="{{ url('/fail') }}">
                    <button type="submit" value="POST TO API">PROCEED/button>
                    </form>
```

After which, https:[www.external.com/api/](http://www.external.com/api/) provides a POST request back to Auth::user() url wherein the data are saved on database.

Controller:

```
public function postfiles(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('user_id',Auth::user()->id);

        return view('postfile');
    }


public function parse(Request $request)
    {
        $files = File::create([
            'Data4'      => $request->input('Data4'),
            'Data5'     => $request->input('Data5'),
            'Data6'       => $request->input('Data6'),
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'Data4'     => $request->input('Data4'),
            'Data5'     => $request->input('Data5'),
            'Data6'     => $request->input('Data6'),
        );

        Auth::loginUsingId($request->session()->get('user_id'));

        return view('success')->with($data);
    }
```

The data are being saved correctly but in the `success.blade.php` I'm getting an error when I try to display the data on the blade.

Error is
`Trying to get property 'username' of non-object`

success.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h3>CONGRATULATIONS {{ Auth::user()->username}}!</h3>
        <h2>The following Data has been saved</h2>
         {{ $Data4}}
         {{ $Data5}}
         {{ $Data6}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'currentUser']], function () {

Route::get('postfile', 'App\Http\Controllers\FileController@postfiles')->name('postfile');

Route::POST('success', 'App\Http\Controllers\FileController@parse')->name('parse');

});
```

It seems the user's session is somehow lost and Auth::user() becomes null after being redirected back during the POST request from the external website.

Comment: cause `Auth::user()` is null as there is no logged-in user. Please add condition to check if user is logged-in or not using either `@auth` or `@guest`

Comment: well, Auth::user() is the one who submits the form, and it seems when the user is redirected back from external website, the session is somehow lost. but i'm just guessing

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why your logged-in user is lost but:

one solution i can say is that you can save id of that user somewhere like coockie or session and after redirecting back from your api, you get that id and **re-login** that user

Comment: I've been looking for this because i don't know how to start it. can you guide me?

Comment: before sending your api request save your user id in session like: Session:put('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
and after redirecting back from your api get that id like: Session:get('user_id') (or you can user coockie instead
now you have your user id and you can loggin him again like: Auth::loginUsingId(Session:get('user_id') )

Comment: this will be done in the controller right?

Comment: does it have something to do with my middleware?